# Unity google playservices pluging produces large amount or erors within its own code

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, plugins, google-play-services

I'm using the plugin for google play services in Unity but when i build my own code in mono-develop (I have not touched any of the plugins code)i receive 27 errors from the plugins classes.I have searched all over and cant find a reason why.The game will build like this but none of the play services work.The first two errors are from the class GPGsAndroidSetupUI at this section of code

```
 Google.VersionHandler.InvokeInstanceMethod(
                GPGSDependencies.svcSupport, "ClearDependencies", null);
            GPGSDependencies.RegisterDependencies();
            Google.VersionHandler.InvokeStaticMethod(
                Google.VersionHandler.FindClass(
                    "Google.JarResolver", "GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver"),
                "MenuResolve", null);
```

Which state that no overload method "InvokeInstanceMethod" takes three arguments

the remaining 25 errors from the class GPGSDependencies but there are all things like "expected ')'" invalid expression term ')' ; expected and invalid expression term ':'

For what its worth the first of these errors is

```
  Google.VersionHandler.UpdateVersionedAssets(forceUpdate: true);
```

There are five errors here and the are ) expected , invalid expression term ';', ; expected twice and invalid expression term ')'

Comment: Try checking this issue in the [GitHub](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues). You can also file a ticket, which can benefit other users of the plugin. Hope this helps.

Comment: Update : i update the playservice plugin to to 0.9.40 and the first two errors have disappeared but the remaining 25 are still there. Also when i call my sign in code i get <App name> connecting to... the the play games logo followed by a green loading icon. The achievements and leader board still do not show nor work